How to handle multiple entypoint like API getway and Lambda invoking in startup while developing API and depoying in AWS Lambda .net core 6 c#?
How to handle multiple entypoint  like API getway and Lambda invoking  in startup while developing API and depoying in AWS Lambda .net core 6 c#?
So that one Lambda, which an API can be consumed from API Gateway and Lambda as well.
public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
       
    protected override void Init(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
    }

    public override Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
    {  
        return base.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, lambdaContext);
    }
}

Here the API calling working but however I need to call from other Lambda also:
public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseLambdaServer();
    }

    public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayProxyRequest request, Amazon.Lambda.Core.ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
    {
        // Your code to handle API Gateway events           
        return await base.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, lambdaContext);
    }

    public async Task<APIResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(System.String input, Amazon.Lambda.Core.ILambdaContext context)
    {
        // Your code to handle other Lambda events
        LambdaLogger.Log($"Received input: {input}");

        // Deserialize the input string into an Request object
        Request request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(input);

        // Call the existing Post method with the deserialized request
        APIResponse response = post.getmethod(request);

        // Return the response
        return response;
    }
}


I created a video for exactly what you're looking for - Building a Serverless ASP.NET Core Web API using AWS Lambda and Amazon API Gateway REST API

Hi  Ankush,Thank you.I saw your video but this is working now in my code but in addition I need to call that API Lambda from another Lambda directly using AmazonLambdaClient .Is that possible?if yes in which way can handle both the API getway and direct Lambda Invoking request to API Lambda.Do you have any idea?
